# C++: Pointers in 2D-arrays are confusing

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

Can someone explain to me what is going on here? Consider the code

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int A[2][2] = {{0}};

    std::cout << A << std::endl;  // First stdout line
    std::cout << *A << std::endl;  // Second stdout line
    std::cout << *(*A) << std::endl;  // Third stdout line
}
```

([Try the code here!](http://cpp.sh/8m33c))

It seems to me that `A` should be an array of 2 pointers to arrays, each of which should contain 2 pointers to `int`s. However, when running the code, the following is written to stdout:

```
0x7a665507cf80
0x7a665507cf80
0
```

To me, this makes it seem like the memory address of the first element in `A` (printed on the first stdout line) is the same as the memory address of the first element in `*A`. How is this possible, considering that `A` and `*A` are clearly two different arrays (since dereferencing `A` and `*A` gives different results)?

An alternative interpretation of the output is that the memory address `0x7a665507cf80` either contains the value `0x7a665507cf80` (i.e. a pointer located on that position—in this case `A`—points to itself) or `0`, depending on if it is accessed from `A` or `*A`, which also doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: Compare `typeid(A)` with `typeid(*A)` - they will be different, since `A` and `*A` have different types, even if they have the same value

Comment: Arrays are not pointers, and pointers are not arrays.

Comment: @molbdnilo I know. Is that important in this case?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye If you know this, why do you believe that `A` "should be an array of 2 pointers to array, each of which should contain 2 pointers to `int`s"?

Comment: Same principle: if you look at any queue of people, you will notice that the beginning of the queue and the first person in the queue are in the same location, even though a queue and a person are totally different things.

Comment: @molbdnilo Ah, of course! I mistakenly thought of `A` as an array of pointers to `int`s (i.e. not proper arrays) instead of an array of arrays. So I thought there has to be some memory allocated for the pointers, which is incorrect since there are no pointers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`int A[2][2] = {{0}};` This is a static 2D array, it's not a pointer to pointer, it's just a 1D array with special access.

The fact that it's not a point to pointer, but a 2D array on a 1D array means that `A[0]` or `*A` accesses the array and returns the 1D array that is the first row. Then the second dereferentiation gets the actual value. This generalizes to nD if you have `int A[x][y][z][t]...`.

So the first two are the "same" address, but they are not the same type.