# Accessing 2D array elements by array names and pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am little confused with 2D arrays. Specially with a formula **`a[i][j] = *(*(a+i)+j)`**
 Before asking my doubt I will like to mention how I think about symbols `'*'` and `'&'`. I think `'&'` is a operator which takes "variable" as operand and gives "address of that variable" and `'*'` takes "address of variable" as a operand and gives "variable" as output, so

`1.*(address)---->>(gives variable)`

`2.&(variable)---->>(gives address)`

(Please tell me if this concept is wrong)

Now suppose there is a 2D array 'a' as follows:

```
a[3][2]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,11,12}}
```

Now I want to access last element of array block i.e `a[3][2]` by using that formula.

**1st Doubt**

So by formula:

```
 a[3][2]=*(*(a+3)+2) // 1
```

I have read that a+3 gives address of first element of 4rt row i.e `&a[3][0]`.
But I have seen people saying that writing a is equivalent to `&a[0][0]`. So subsituting in equation (1)

```
a[3][2] *(*(&a[0][0] +3)+2)
```

So adding 3 to `&a[0][0]` means giving adress of the block `a[1][0]`.....(going three blocks forward of `a[0][0]`). So here our (a+3) has pointed us to `&a[1][0]` and not to `&a[3][0]`.

**2nd Doubt**

Suppose now evaluating (a+3) really gives me address of a[3][0] (which is correct). So equation (1) now becomes

`a[3][2]=*(*(&a[3][0])+2)`

Using my concept

`*(address of variable)---->>(gives variable)`

So`*(&a[3][0])= a[3][0]`. So a[3][0] should be a variable storing value 10. Now we have then, `a[3][2]=*(10+2)=*(12)`. But now `'*'`operator needs adress as input and we are giving a r-value which is not a address, so this should give an error.

I know there is a hell lot of mistake in my concepts but I am a beginner and just started C language as my 1st topic in field of programming, please help me out.

Comment: Folks need to chill out with the minor edits so people can actually read the question.

Comment: The question's original formatting is really unconventional and hard to follow. Please, ease up on bold!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: Pointers in 2D-arrays are confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53445395/c-pointers-in-2d-arrays-are-confusing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think '&' is a operator which takes variable as operand and gives address of that variable…

This is not quite correct. We ought to clarify what a “variable” is. What is often called a variable is, in C, an identifier and an object. The identifier is the text string we use as the name. For example, in `int xyz;`, “xyz” is the identifier. The object is the region of memory used to represent the value. So, in `int xyz;`, the object is a few bytes (often four) the compiler reserves somewhere in memory.

The `&` operator gives the address of the object (or function) to which it is applied. Note that it does not need to be applied to a variable, just to any object (or function). So, instead of a named object, it can be applied to some computed thing (as in `&a[i+4]`) or to a string literal (`&"abc"`) or compound literal (`& (int []) {3, 4, 5}`).

> … and '*' reversibly takes adress of variable as a operand and gives variable as output,

The `*` takes a pointer to an object (or function, not further discussed here) and produces the object (specifically, an lvalue that designates the object). The object does not have to be the object of a named variable; it can be an array element or a dynamically allocated object or something else.

> Now suppose there is a 2D array 'a' as follows:
>
> a[3][2]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,11,12}}

That is not a correct array definition, because it has no element type and because it says the array dimensions are 3 and 2, but the list of initializers show the dimensions should be 4 and 3. Let’s suppose we correct it to:

```
int a[4][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12} };
```

> I have read that a+3 gives address of first element of 4th row i.e &a[3][0].

Not quite. In the expression `a+3`, `a` designates an array. That array is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, so it is equivalent to `&a[0]`. Note that the type of this expression is an array of 3 `int`—it is a subarray of `a`. When we add 3 to this, the compiler counts 3 subarrays, so `a+3` points to the subarray number 3 (starting the numbering from 0). Thus `a+3` is equivalent to `&a[3]`.

`&a[3]` is the address of subarray number 3. This is not the same as `&a[3][0]`, which is the address of element number 0 of subarray number 3. Although they, in effect, point to the same place in memory, they have different types, and the compiler treats them differently.

> But I have seen people saying that writing a is equivalent to &a[0][0].

That is incorrect. `a` is equivalent to `&a[0]`—it is a pointer to the first element of `a`. The first element of `a` is itself an array; it is `a[0]`, not `a[0][0]`. Although `&a[0]` and `&a[0][0]` may in effect point to the same place in memory, they have different types, and the compiler will treat them differently.

> So subsituting in equation (1)

Since `a` is not equivalent to `&a[0][0]`, the latter cannot be substituted for the former.

Let’s go back to the formula you mentioned:

> a[i][j] = *(*(a+i)+j)

This is correct. Recall that `a` is automatically converted to `&a[0]`. Then `&a[0]+i` counts `i` subarrays, and the result of the addition is equal to `&a[i]`. Then, in `*(a+i)`, we apply the `*` operator. This changes `&a[i]` to `*&a[i]`. Since `&a[i]` points to `a[i]`, `*&a[i]` is `a[i]`.

Now, we have figured out that `*(a+i)` becomes `a[i]`, and we want to figure out what `*(a+i)+j` is. In effect, we are asking what `a[i]+j` is. So we have to figure out what happens to `a[i]` in this expression.

Recall that `a[i]` is a subarray of `a`. So it is itself an array. When used in an expression, an array is automatically converted to the address of its first element (except when used as the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&`). So `a[i]` is converted to `&a[i][0]`. Then we add `j`, producing `&a[i][0] + j`. Since `&a[i][0]` is a pointer to an `int`, the compiler counts `j` `int` and produces a pointer to `a[i][j]`. That is, the result of `*(a+i)+j` is `&a[i][j]`. Then applying `*` produces `*&a[i][j]`, which is `a[i][j]`.

Comment: What will be the output for a statement printf("%u",a). As u said array name is converted to pointer to its first element, so a=&a [0]. So it is pointing to first sub array having index 0. But this sub array has 3 more elements in it, so whose address it will print. Is it a [0][0] / a [0][1] / a [0][3] ?

Comment: @Avi: Do not use `%u` to print pointers. You can print a pointer with `printf("%p", (void *) a);`. Technically, the compiler is free to represent pointers in various ways. Most modern implementations in flat address spaces simply use the address of the first byte of an object. Since `a`, `a[0]`, and `a[0][0]` are all objects starting at the same first byte, their addresses will appear to be equal when printed with `%p` in most modern C implementations. In some sense, this is an illusion: There is no way to compare two pointers of different types. At least one of them must be converted first.

Comment: That is, if you write an expression `&a[0] == &a[0][0]`, it is not well defined by the C standard. You must instead convert them to a common type, as with `(char *) &a[0] == (char *) &a[0][0]`. This conversion to `char *` will produce a pointer to the first byte of an object. Since the objects have the same first byte, this comparison will evaluate to true.